# how to group data of an object by value and give key object a specific name?

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, types, rxjs

hi everyone a need help to formatting this object in a specific way:

```
[
  {
    data: '2020-02-24 18:00:00',
    stato: 'ITA',
    codice_regione: 10,
    denominazione_regione: 'Umbria',
    lat: 43.10675841,
    long: 12.38824698,
    ricoverati_con_sintomi: 0,
    terapia_intensiva: 0,
    totale_ospedalizzati: 0,
    isolamento_domiciliare: 0,
    totale_attualmente_positivi: 0,
    nuovi_attualmente_positivi: 0,
    dimessi_guariti: 0,
    deceduti: 0,
    totale_casi: 0,
    tamponi: 0
  },
  {
    data: '2020-02-25 18:00:00',
    stato: 'ITA',
    codice_regione: 10,
    denominazione_regione: 'Umbria',
    lat: 43.10675841,
    long: 12.38824698,
    ricoverati_con_sintomi: 0,
    terapia_intensiva: 0,
    totale_ospedalizzati: 0,
    isolamento_domiciliare: 0,
    totale_attualmente_positivi: 0,
    nuovi_attualmente_positivi: 0,
    dimessi_guariti: 0,
    deceduti: 0,
    totale_casi: 0,
    tamponi: 8
  },
  {
    data: '2020-02-24 18:00:00',
    stato: 'ITA',
    codice_regione: 11,
    denominazione_regione: 'Marche',
    lat: 43.61675973,
    long: 13.5188753,
    ricoverati_con_sintomi: 0,
    terapia_intensiva: 0,
    totale_ospedalizzati: 0,
    isolamento_domiciliare: 0,
    totale_attualmente_positivi: 0,
    nuovi_attualmente_positivi: 0,
    dimessi_guariti: 0,
    deceduti: 0,
    totale_casi: 0,
    tamponi: 16
  },
  {
    data: '2020-02-25 18:00:00',
    stato: 'ITA',
    codice_regione: 11,
    denominazione_regione: 'Marche',
    lat: 43.61675973,
    long: 13.5188753,
    ricoverati_con_sintomi: 0,
    terapia_intensiva: 0,
    totale_ospedalizzati: 0,
    isolamento_domiciliare: 0,
    totale_attualmente_positivi: 0,
    nuovi_attualmente_positivi: 0,
    dimessi_guariti: 0,
    deceduti: 0,
    totale_casi: 0,
    tamponi: 21
  }
]
```

I need something like this, for groups the value of all days whit this lecture of data in a data model like this, whit the name of a region and all the characteristics related to that region.

```
[
  {
    "Umbria":[
      {
        "ricoverati_con_sintomi":{
          "name":"ricoverati_con_sintomi",
          "data":[
            ["2020-02-24 18:00:00",0],
            ["2020-02-25 18:00:00",0]
          ]
        }
      "terapia_intensiva":{
          "name":"terapia_intensiva",
          "data":[
            ["2020-02-24 18:00:00",0],
            ["2020-02-25 18:00:00",0]
          ]
        }
       ... other values of the orinal json ...
      }
    ],
    "Marche":[
      {
        "ricoverati_con_sintomi":{
          "name":"ricoverati_con_sintomi",
          "data":[
            ["2020-02-24 18:00:00",0],
            ["2020-02-25 18:00:00",0]
          ]
        },
        "terapia_intensiva":{
          "name":"terapia_intensiva",
          "data":[
            ["2020-02-24 18:00:00",0],
            ["2020-02-25 18:00:00",0]
          ]
        }
      ... other values of the orinal json ...
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

i need all the value of the original json, but not this

```
   stato: 'ITA',
      codice_regione: 10,
      denominazione_regione: 'Umbria',
      lat: 43.10675841,
      long: 12.38824698,
```

i have no idea how to made it! please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose that the data in your first snippet is in stored in a list called `list`. I'll tackle this step by step so you can better understand the solution. **Please note that this will not be an optimized solution by a long shot, but just one that is easy to follow.**

I will also avoid any use of `map`, `filter`, `reduce` or similar in favor of iterating over a list, object entries or object keys via a for..of loop to minimise any unfamiliar syntax. Links to explanations of the used syntax that may be unfamiliar can be found at the end of the answer. Feel free to ask me any questions in the comments.

#### Step 1: Group by region

Group all the data in a dictionary where the region name is the key and the item is a list element.

```js
const dataByRegion = {};
for (const item of list) {
   if (!dataByRegion[item.denominazione_regione]) {
       // create a list if it does not exist
       dataByRegion[item.denominazione_regione] = [];
   }
   // add item to list
   dataByRegion[item.denominazione_regione].push(item);
}
```

#### Step 2: Group by characteristic

Now there are two ways to go about this, if all the items have all the same characteristics then just store them in a list called `CHARACTERISTIC_NAMES`, if not, but you know the properties that are not characteristic names, sore them in a list called `NOT_CHARACTERISTIC_NAMES`:

```
const CHARACTERISTIC_NAMES = ['ricoverati_con_sintomi', 'terapia_intensiva', ...]
const NOT_CHARACTERISTIC_NAMES = ['dato', 'stato', 'denominazione_regione'...]
```

Now iterate over each of the lists in the dictionary and group them in a new one that is by region and characteristic (i.e. it's a dictionary that has the region name for its key and another dictionary for its value where the characteristic is the key).

```js
const dataByRegionAndCharacteristic = {};
for (const [region_name, list] of Object.entries(dataByRegion)) {
    dataByRegionAndCharacteristic[region_name] = {}
    for (const item of list) {
        for (const key of Object.keys(item)) {
             if (/* key **is not** a part of CHARACTERISTIC_NAMES or **is** a part of NOT_CHARACTERISTIC_NAMES */) {
                 continue;
             }
             if (!dataByRegionAndCharacteristic[region_name][key]) {
                 dataByRegionAndCharacteristic[region_name][key] = [];
             }
             dataByRegionAndCharacteristic[region_name][key].push(item);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Step 3: Get rid of extra data

You'll notice that the `dataByRegionAndCharacteristic` is close to what you want to accomplish, but you only want one object for each region and characteristic pair that has its name and an array of date and count pairs, let's make a v2 that has the data formatted like that:

```js
const dataByRegionAndCharacteristicV2 = {};
for (const [region_name, dataByCharacteristic] of Object.entries(dataByRegionAndCharacteristic)) {
    dataByRegionAndCharacteristicV2[region_name] = {};
    for (const [name, list] of Object.entries(dataByRegionAndCharacteristic[region_name])) {
        dataByRegionAndCharacteristicV2[region_name][name] = { name: name, data: [] };
        for (const item of list) {
            const dateAndCountPair = [item.dato, item[name]];
            dataByRegionAndCharacteristicV2[region_name][name].push(dateAndCountPair);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Step 4: The inner dictionary is actually an array

You'll notice that dataByRegionAndCharacteristicV2 is just a bit off of the required format. The inner part isn't supposed to be an object but a list, so let's make a v3 to format it correctly:

```js
const dataByRegionAndCharacteristicV3 = {};
for (const [region_name, dataByCharacteristic] of Object.entries(dataByRegionAndCharacteristic2)) {
    dataByRegionAndCharacteristicV3[region_name] = [];
    for (const [name, data] of Object.entries(dataByRegionAndCharacteristicV2[region_name])) {
        const obj = { [name]: data };
        dataByRegionAndCharacteristicV3[region_name].push(obj);
    }
}
```

And you're done :D

---

#### Additionaly

Steps 2-4 can easily be done as a part of the same loop, I've separated them for readability sake. What's more is that all the steps can be a part of the same loop. None of these steps requires additional memory to remember what was in some item before or after, you just need to structure you're data correctly from the start and fill it in appropriately.

---

Syntax resources:

- [for..of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)
- [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)
- [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)
- [Object initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)

Answer (score 2):

Did you try reduce functions in javascript? Seems like it is what you need.

From array -> to mapped object.

```
[
  {
    "regione": "marche",
    "dato 1": "test 1",
    "dato 2": "test 2"
  },
  {
    "regione": "piemonte",
    "dato 1": "test 3",
    "dato 2": "test 4"
  }
].reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr.regione] = Object.keys(curr).reduce((data, currKey) => {
    data[currKey] = curr[currKey];
    return data;
  }, {});
  return acc;
}, {});
```

Please, use this example to get familiar with reduce method and apply your logic to handle the JSON.